# Performing instance methods in a for loop of an NSMutableArray(Containing 3 objects)

Tags: objective-c

I'm following the Big Nerd Ranch's guide to objective-C, in one of the challenges(Chapter 17), he asks you to make 3 instance of an object that you've created, I've made the class, implemented the setters, getters and two instance methods, I've then created 3 instances of the object and defined all of the variables. He then asks you to put the 3 objects into an array and iterate the values with a for loop.

the problem I'm having is that I don't know how to perform an instance method within a "for loop".

This is what I have so far (All values are random and hypothetical):

StockHolding.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface StockHolding : NSObject
{
    float purchaseSharePrice;
    float currentSharePrice;
    int numberOfShares;
}

@property float purchaseSharePrice;
@property float currentSharePrice;
@property int numberOfShares;

- (float)costInDollars;
- (float)valueInDollars;

@end
```

StockHolding.m

```
#import "StockHolding.h"

@implementation StockHolding

@synthesize purchaseSharePrice, currentSharePrice, numberOfShares;

- (float)costInDollars;
{
    return purchaseSharePrice * numberOfShares;
}
- (float)valueInDollars;
{
    return currentSharePrice * numberOfShares;
}

@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StockHolding.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

    StockHolding *apple = [[StockHolding alloc] init];

        [apple setPurchaseSharePrice: 10];
        [apple setCurrentSharePrice: 50];
        [apple setNumberOfShares: 20];

    StockHolding *hmv = [[StockHolding alloc] init];

        [hmv setPurchaseSharePrice: 15];
        [hmv setCurrentSharePrice: 0];
        [hmv setNumberOfShares: 17];

    StockHolding *drpepper = [[StockHolding alloc] init];

        [drpepper setPurchaseSharePrice: 5];
        [drpepper setCurrentSharePrice: 15];
        [drpepper setNumberOfShares: 70];


        NSMutableArray *stocksList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:apple, hmv, drpepper, nil];

        for (NSObject z in stocksList) {

            NSLog(@"Original cost: %@", [z costInDollars]);
            NSLog(@"Current value: %@", [z valueInDollars]);

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That *should* work as long as you have your type of the variable `z` set properly.

Comment: You can use `StockHolding *` in for inplace of `NSObject`

Comment: @scott: are you getting any error ?

Comment: NSObject*, not NSObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your home work is fine.

It is difficult to find mistakes without compiling.

- in `NSLog` you used %@ for `[stockObj  costInDollars]` which returns `float`, so here is an error. Use `%f`

You just need some touch-up on your code.

1. Good Naming convention.
2. Use `for(StockHolding *stockObj in stocksList)` in place of `for (NSObject z in stocksList)`

   ```
   for (StockHolding *stockObj in stocksList) {
       NSLog(@"Original cost: %f", [stockObj  costInDollars]);//%f as costInDollars returns float not an object
       NSLog(@"Current value: %f", [stockObj  valueInDollars]);//same as above
   }
   ```
3. ivars can be skipped, @property will work good.
4. @synthesize is not required in new compiler. If you use, try to use one property per line.
5. Instead of assigning values as :

   ```
   StockHolding *apple = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
   [apple setPurchaseSharePrice: 10];
   [apple setCurrentSharePrice: 50];
   [apple setNumberOfShares: 20];
   ```

   You can use :

   ```
   StockHolding *apple=[[StockHolding alloc]initWithPurchaseSharePrice:10 currentSharePrice:50 numberOfShares:20];
   ```

   For this you need to create a method :

   ```
   -(StockHolding *)initWithPurchaseSharePrice:(float)purchase currentSharePrice:(float)current numberOfShares(int):numbers];
   ```
6. Instead of `NSMutableArray *stocksList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:apple, hmv, drpepper, nil];` you can use:

   ```
   NSMutableArray *stocksList=@[apple, hmv, drpepper];
   ```

EDIT:

To print stockObject: Call following method as `[self printStockObject:stockObject];`

```
-(void)printStockObject:(StockHolding *)stockObj{
    NSLog(@"Purchase Price : %f",stockObj.purchaseSharePrice);
    NSLog(@"Current Price : %f",stockObj.currentSharePrice);
    NSLog(@"Number of Shares : %d",stockObj.numberOfShares);
}
```

Comment: As well as your original answer for the problem I also needed to implement point #2, I had tried %f before and it hadn't worked, that's why I changed it to %@, changing NSObject to StockHolding did the trick. thanks a million! - Would you also know how I can print the name of the stockObj in NSLOG? I've tried NSLog(@"%@", stockObj); but it just returns the memory address.

Comment: You cann't print an object directly, it will print memory address. You need to print its property values...Check my Edit in answer.

Comment: I'm talking about printing the name of the object, so for instance printing "Original cost of my Apple shares: xxx", "Current value of my Apple Shares: xxx".

Comment: @ScottBrowne, see my answer for that.

Comment: @ScottBrowne, you cant print the name of a variable. it gets lost during compilation. Add it as a property to your class.

Comment: @ScottBrowne: if you want to print variableName say "apple" in your case, why dont you put another property to the class `NSString *name` and assign it to @"apple".

Comment: I think I must be half asleep, I tried doing this but I didn't make "name" a pointer >.< I may give it a rest for today lol, thanks for all the help, I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> Would you also know how I can print the name of the stockObj in NSLOG? I've tried NSLog(@"%@", stockObj); but it just returns the memory address.

overwrite `-description`

```
-(NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: purchase price: %f current price: %f, number of shares: %d", NSStringFromClass([self class]), self.purchaseSharePrice, self. currentSharePrice, self.numberOfShares];
}
```

If you also want the `description` of the super class, do

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: purchase price: %f current price: %f, number of shares: %d %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), self.purchaseSharePrice, self. currentSharePrice, self.numberOfShares, [super description]];
```

---

AKV wrote, that you should loop like this:

```
for (StockHolding *stockObj in stocksList) {
   NSLog(@"%@",stockObj);
}
```

This is correct. But if you have other objects than `StockHolding` in that list, you also could do

```
for (id stockObj in stocksList) {
    NSLog(@"%@",stockObj);
}
```

as you can send any message to `id` — if it is implemented, it will work, otherwise crash. note that NSObject and `id`are not the same.

---

In modern version of Xcode you dont need to declare iVars. neither you need to synthesize.

```
@interface StockHolding : NSObject

@property float purchaseSharePrice;
@property float currentSharePrice;
@property int numberOfShares;
@property (copy) NSString *shareName;


- (float)costInDollars;
- (float)valueInDollars;

@end
```

if you dont synthesize, the ivars name will be the name of the property with a `_`-prefix

`shareName` -> `_shareName`

```
StockHolding *apple = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
[apple setPurchaseSharePrice: 10];
[apple setCurrentSharePrice: 50];
[apple setNumberOfShares: 20];
[apple setShareName:@"apple"];
```

`-description` could look like

```
-(NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@ purchase price: %f current price: %f, number of shares: %d", NSStringFromClass([self class]),_shareName, self.purchaseSharePrice, self. currentSharePrice, self.numberOfShares];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what iVars are, I've just learnt about Setter/Getters, and it seems like that would be what iVars are, if I'm right, does that means that my getter would be "shareName" and my setter would be "_shareName" - I've actually got the code working how I'd like it with the help of AKV, Thanks for your help, I think the rest of the work I'd need to do is just making the code more terse, given that I've achieved my goal, curtness of the code isn't that important to me so I'm going to move on, I completely understand what you mean though. Thanks again!

Comment: no, ivars are the "instance variables", getter/setter access them, but are methods `[self setShareName:@"apple"]`, and properties are a way to generate those getter/setters, and allow to access this setter with dot-notoation (`self.sharename = @"apple";`).

Comment: but if this is new to you, you should check the *Programming with Objective-C* by apple now.

Comment: Well I'm using the Big Nerd Ranch's guide and the tutor has discussed dot notation and in his opinion it confuses thing and isn't worth it, obviously this is his opinion, not mine, but I'm going to skip them for now and make my own mind up when I have a better grasp of the language. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, u still need to know the difference. And I don't like BNR for telling you what to do but barely giving you a real understanding.

Comment: I may not have explained correctly,  I know/understand "Instance variables", "getters/setters" and "dot notations", what I was saying was, that the guide doesn't use "dot notations" as the tutor doesn't like them, he prefers to use the long hand to keep the code clear, so he teaches dot notation, he just doesn't condone it within his guide. http://imgur.com/NpFSfMJ